# How to hide connection passwords in Hikari CP DEBUG logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to mask the password while printing debug logs in hikariconfig

Sample logs for where I want to hide the password

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig

- dataSourceProperties............{url=JDBC_URL, SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=**Password@123**, IFMXCONNECTION_CLEANER_THREADS=0, DATABASE=USERDB, user=ABC, LOGINTIMEOUT=5000, SSLCONNECTION=TRUE, IFX_ISOLATION_LEVEL=1, SSL_PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.2, DB_LOCALE=en_US.819, password=**Password@123**, IFX_PREPAREDSTATEMENT_CACHE_SIZE=20, SSL_TRUSTSTORE=TRUSTSTORE_PATH, CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.utf8}

Comment: You should mask password in spring boot log

Comment: I am using Jersey

Comment: wanted to know how to mask those logs which are directly printing by Hikari and that too for custom connection properties

Comment: You should search for general masking in spring bot logging, In jersey you can add filter https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-custom-logging-request-and-response-entities-using-filter/

Comment: so would that mean overriding each log and checking when there is a password mask it?

Comment: It depends on your company needs, you can also remove hikari logs using log configuration as set log level ERROR for its package